# Gunicorn cannot find system Renviron error

Tags: python, r, django, virtualenv, gunicorn

I have been struggling with this for days, reaching my limit.

I am porting a Django project from using mod_wsgi/httpd to use gunicorn/nginx

I have set up a virtual environment using virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper and pip installed the requirements file into it, as well a gunicorn. The django project is a very complex site with lots of dependencies.

When I start the app using

```
 `python manage.py runserver`
```

everything runs fine with no errors. However when I try to start with gunicorn

```
`gunicorn wsgi`
```

I get this error

````
```
    cannot find system Renviron
    Fatal error: unable to open base package
```
````

I don't even know where to start troubleshooting this. I have added .Renviron files to my user directory, added `os.environ["Renviron"]=/path` to both the wsgi.py and settings.py files, downgraded RPy2 back to 2.5.6. Nothing seems to help. I don't know what else to do. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my set up:

```
MacOS High Sierra (10.13.5) running in Parallels Desktop Lite 1.3.3 VM
Django==1.9.2
gunicorn=19.9.0
gevent==1.3.4
greenlet==0.4.13
whitenoise==3.3.1
rpy2==2.5.6
Homebrew==1.6.17
R=3.5.1
```

**Django wsgi.py file**

```
    """
    WSGI config for ri project.
    """
    import os, sys, socket, site
    dev_path = "/Users/evans/.virtualenvs/base_env/"

    os.environ["R_HOME"]='/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Renviron'
    os.environ["Renviron"]='/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Renviron'

    host = socket.gethostname()
    print "HOST: ",host

    site.addsitedir(dev_path+'lib/python2.7/site-packages')

    # Activate the virtual environment
    # Taken from http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/
    activate_env = os.path.expanduser(dev_path+'bin/activate_this.py')
    execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

    sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/local/var/django/code')
    sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/local/var/django/code/ri')

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ri.settings")

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Django settings.py file**

```
    # Django settings for ri project.
    import socket
    import sys
    import os

    os.environ["Renviron"]="/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Renviron"
    Renviron="/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Renviron"
    R_HOME="/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Renviron"
    
    host = socket.gethostname()

    BASE_PATH="/usr/local/var/django/code"

    DEBUG = True # will not send email if True, Runserver will not serve static files if False

    if DEBUG:
        EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

    ADMINS = (('Mark Evans',),)
    MANAGERS = ADMINS
    TESTING = 'test' in sys.argv

    # explicitly naming this is asked for in django > 1.6
    TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'

    DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
    # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
                       'NAME': 'foodb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
                       # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
                       'USER': 'fooadmin',
                       'PASSWORD': 'foo_admin',
                       'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
                       'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
                      },
    }

    if TESTING:
        DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
                           'NAME': 'test_db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
                           # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
                           'USER': 'foo',
                           'PASSWORD': 'foo_admin',
                           'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
                           'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
                          }
    }

    # Test runner with no database creation
    TEST_RUNNER = 'ri.RiTestRunner.RiTestRunner'

    # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    SITE_ID = 1
    USE_I18N = False
    USE_L10N = True
    USE_TZ = False

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'ri.urls'
    SETTINGS_FILE_FOLDER = BASE_PATH + '/ri'
    #default login redirect path
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

    # Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
    # Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_PATH + '/media'

    # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
    # trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
    # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
    # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
    # Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_PATH + '/static/'
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Additional locations of static files
    STATICFILES_DIRS = ( BASE_PATH + '/static_src/',)

    # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
    # various locations.
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')

    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

    # Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
    SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ BASE_PATH+"/ri/templates",],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'debug_panel.middleware.DebugPanelMiddleware',
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
        # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
        # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        # the following class logs out a user after AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY amount of time
        'ri.middleware.AutoLogout',
    )

    # Add automatic caching and compression support
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
            'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        },

    # this cache backend will be used by django-debug-panel
    'debug-panel': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/debug-panel-cache',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 200
        }
    }
    }


    # Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ri.wsgi.application'

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.admindocs',
        'django.contrib.postgres',
        'debug_toolbar',
        'debug_panel',

        # Put RI apps below this line in alphabetical order
        'ri',               # in order to access project, target, etc
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** - So I was never able to actually find a solution to the problem per se. However I was able to isolate it by commenting out the apps in the INSTALLED_APPS section of settings.py until I found the app that was responsible for the R dependency. Turns out I didn't need it, so I removed that app and now things work.

Still an odd situation though.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `R_HOME` does not look right.  It should be the name of a directory, like `"/usr/local/lib/R"`, not a file.

That said, R may start up just fine by itself, but appears prone to this issue (cannot find system Renviron) when you try to use it from another language, be it Python, Java, or Tcl.  It may require the `R_HOME` environment variable, which it normally doesn't need.